Previous Week Duration Sum PowerPivot
I need to get the previous week sum total in a column on PowerPivot.
I have tried the below in Both a custom column and as a measure.
my data table has dates, and a duration column as well as a custom WEEKNUM column.
=CALCULATE(
    SUM(FAULTDATA[DURATION]),
    FAULTDATA[WEEK NUM] = FAULTDATA[WEEK NUM]-1)

however it isn't working, any ideas please?
I will be using this to form a helper column for conditional formatting of increase or decrease markers.
Thanks

you're not modifying the evaluation context (the week number).
Total Duration := SUM('Table1'[Duration])

Total Duration Previous Week
CALCULATE(
[Total Duration],
FILTER(ALL('Table1'[WeekNum]),
    'Table1'[WeekNum] = MAX('Table1'[WeekNum]) - 1
    )
)

(You're missing the MAX() part. "return only the current weeknumber" bit.

Thank you, this does bring through the correct figure but its also bringing through all employees even when they are not in the selected slicer month/week :(
